# Use an existing variable as src attribute for html audio

Tags: var, src

On the server side there is an existing variable named "audioFile" that works as an expression in this href:

```
<div class="see-other-results-text">
<a href="{{ audioFile }}">Audio File</a> 
</div>
```

...the link goes to the audio file.

Im trying to use the same variable "audioFile" as a src for my audio player:

```
<audio controls>
<source class="audioSrc" src="{{ audioFile }}" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

...without success.

Comment: It should work fine as I just tried here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hvwhwo

Comment: There's no JavaScript here. `{{ audioFile }}` looks like it's part of a template framework.